# How to convert high voltage DC at low amps to low voltage DC or AC at high amps?

Tags: high-voltage, conversion, low-voltage, earth, electrostatic

How to convert high voltage 500 volts DC at very low amps to lower voltage  12 volt DC or AC at high amps? Must I use an electrostatic motor or can I use an op amp?

The reason I am posing this is a desire to send up a wire to convert atmospheric electricity to something I can use.

Comment: What is atmospheric electricity at 500v?

Comment: You may be able to design a special-purpose DC-DC converter, but... What is the atmospheric electricity you reference?

Comment: The 500 volts is a rough estimate of the voltage from the ground to the roof of my house. Unfortunately, the current would be in picoamps. I once saw an article about a boy who developed enough amps to charge a cell phone from a vertical wire.

Comment: In addition to charge, you can collect EM/RF energy in the same way as my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to adapt something from the ["solar engine"](http://solarbotics.net/library.html) guys.
They have a lot of circuit variants that take small amounts of charge and store it in a capacitor until enough energy is available, then discharge it all at once to do something useful.  Due to your input voltage you'll have to pick appropriately rated transistors.